# Point on the ring of the circle / limit drag indicator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project where I'm making a drag indicator (Below)

[image]

Is someone able to tell me how can I limit the length of this indicator?

I create it with this code

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                if (lr == null)
                {
                    lr = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
                }
                lr.enabled = true;
                lr.positionCount = 2;
                startPos = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) + camOffset;
                lr.SetPosition(0, startPos);
                lr.useWorldSpace = true;
                lr.widthCurve = ac;
                lr.numCapVertices = 10;
                lr.sortingLayerName = "Top";
                lr.startColor = Color.white;
                lr.endColor = Color.white;
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                endPos = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) + camOffset;
                lr.SetPosition(1, endPos);

            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                lr.enabled = false;
                attached = false;
            }
```

I have tried to limit the length like this

```
Vector3 length = startPos - endPos;
if(length.magnitude <= 7) lr.SetPosition(1, endPos);
```

But it results in having no endPos updates after I go past the length of 7.

Any idea of how to achieve the limit while still updating the endPos?

Comment: This is a question about your code, rather than the Visual Studio application itself, so I've removed the `[visual-studio]` tag. I recommend always reading the descriptions of the tags you use to ensure that you don't accidentally misuse them. You can do so by hovering over the tag and clicking "view tag". The description and usage guidelines will appear at the top of the resulting page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vector3 direction = endPos - startPos;
float length = direction.magnitude;
if(length > 7) 
    endPos = startPos + direction / length * 7;
lr.SetPosition(1, endPos);
```

Note: I'm using `direction / length` rather than `direction.normalized`, to avoid expensive duplicate calculation of `direction.magnitude`